# Взаимное заполнение EditText-ов

Tags: java, android

***Задача чтоб, при изменении первого editText'а изменялся 2-ой, а при изменении 2-го - первый.***

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
etNum2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
etNum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);




etNum.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if(s.toString().length()>0){
            h.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null); // Cancels previous call
            h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                   num1 = Float.parseFloat(etNum.getText().toString());
                        vivod = ((1/Float.parseFloat(r))*Float.parseFloat(k))*num1;


                    String str = String.valueOf(vivod);
                    etNum2.setText(str);


                }
            }, 10); // 1 second
        }
        else{

        }
    }
});
```

Пока у меня получилось сделать только так, если пытаюсь изменить второе, просто в обоих нули и их не изменить никак. Пробовал создать новый листнер, ничего не получилось, надеюсь кто-то мне подскажет. Спасибо

Comment: Что вы хотите?. Изменять 1 edit и аналогично менялся второй ? Опишите подробней, тогда вам быстрей и точней ответят.

Comment: Что такое *"Взаимное заменине"*?

Comment: @Pandoxa вам необходимо чтоб каждый editText имел TextWatcher в нем и будет логика. Можно сделать общий зависит от той же самой логики. Я думаю скоро вам дадут хороший и показательный ответ. Задача проста.

Answer (score 4):

`TextWatcher` реагирует на любое изменение текста. Если просто повесить на оба - то они зацикливаются, бесконечно изменяя друг друга и реагируя на эти же изменения.
Нужно добавить условия, когда листенер должен сработать, а когда нет.
Например, проверить в фокусе ли наш `EditText` (оба сразу не могут быть в фокусе):

```
etNum.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if (!etNum.hasFocus())
            return;
        if (s.toString().length() > 0) {
            num1 = Float.parseFloat(etNum.getText().toString());
            vivod = ((1/Float.parseFloat(r))*Float.parseFloat(k))*num1;
            String str = String.valueOf(vivod);
            etNum2.setText(str);
        }
    }
});
```